# xslt for substring- before or get a specific value for an input

Tags: xslt, substring, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt and still trying to learn
My question 1 is:
The input request is

```
<value>120KV</value> or <value>120MV</value> or <value>120GV</value>
```

I want an xslt function which can get me "k", 'M", "G"
i am using xslt 1.0

```
<tns:multiplier>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before (//ns0:value,'V'>"/>
 </tns:multiplier>
```

which gives me result as 120K or 120M or 120G
But i want the output only as "K" or "M" or "G". I want to jus extract 1 character before V and after the numbers. It can be anything . In the examples above its K, M,G
How can i do that?

My second question is after i get the value i want to convert "K" to lower case and keep "M" and"G"as it is in upper case
So my final output should be

```
<tns:multiplier>k</tns:multiplier> or <tns:multiplier>M</tns:multiplier> or <tns:multiplier>G</tns:multiplier>
```

Thanks in adv

Comment: It is not clear whether you want the last character in that substring you have extracted or whether you want to implement some other rules (removing all digits, for example). But `substring` or `translate` should help.

Comment: A simple `translate(value, 'KV0123456789', 'k')` should give you the result you want.

Comment: I want to extract jus 1 character that is before ‘V’ and after the numbers. It can be anything, in this example it is K, M,G. I do not want the numbers

Comment: If there is only one character between the numbers and the "V" (and no characters before the numbers or after the "V"), the above expression will extract it.

Comment: Thank you so much that works